# How to remove parentheses and blank spaces from a sentence?

Tags: python, regex

I know the question title is similar to many other questions, but I have also read those answers but didn't work for my case. I have a some strings which are like below:

```
s = '（ANTENOR）'
s = '（ねぼけ）'
```

Strings are sometimes in English and sometimes in Japanes. I tried different solutions given in StackOverflow but in my case, those aren't working. For example, I tried the following one, but didn't work in my case:

```
s = re.sub(r'[()]', '', s)
```

But not working and returns the same string as the original.

My Output should look like below:

```
ANTENOR
ねぼけ
```

Only the text, no brackets, and no parentheses. Any help?

Comment: You can use ```.strip()```, then remove brackets through regex

Comment: The parentheses you're trying to remove are not the normal parentheses, but variant ones (maybe fullwidth). Copy and paste them into the regex instead of typing them.

Comment: @Sujay why not just use [**`.strip('（）')`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't a classic parenthesis, that is [FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff08/index.htm).
You can see it using `ord`. And there isn't even a space, there is only char and it has some space before, in it

```
# yours
print(ord('（'))  # 65288
# classic parenthesis
print(ord('('))  # 40
```

---

The solution to remove them, is to copy/paste them in the regex

```
s = '（ANTENOR）'
s = re.sub(r'[）（]', '', s)
print(f">{s}<")  # >ANTENOR<

s = '（ねぼけ）'
s = re.sub(r'[）（]', '', s)
print(f">{s}<")  # >ねぼけ<
```